# Create threads dynamically depending on time needs of single tasks

Tags: c++, multithreading

Say I have a list of callable objects like

```cpp
std::list<std::shared_ptr<Callable>> tasks;
```

and the task is to run them all in an infinite loop, say

```cpp
void run_all(const bool& abort){
   while(true){
      for(const auto& ptr : tasks){
         if (abort) return;
         (*ptr)();
      }
   }
}
```

This is fine as long as every "task" finishes after short time. Now I'd like to add the requirement that whenever a task needs more time than a specific `threshold`, a new thread should be created so that the other tasks do not have do wait for a specific long running task.

The simplest solution regarding code complexity I can think of at the moment would be creating a thread for each task:

```cpp
void run_all(const bool& abort){
   auto job = [&](std::shared_ptr<Callable> task){
      while (!abort){
         (*task)();
      }
   };
   std::list<std::thread> threads;
   for(auto& ptr : tasks){
      threads.emplace_back(job, ptr);
   }
   for(auto& t : threads){
      t.join();
   }
}
```

But this might create inappropriate many threads.
What is an appropriate way to implement running the tasks and create threads dynamically depending on how long a tasks needs to be finished? Say we have got some

```cpp
std::chrono::duration threshold;
```

and the goal is to run the first task and continue with the next afterwards if the first one takes no longer than `threshold` until finish, but create a new thread to run the rest of the tasks in parallel, if the first task does not finish before threashold. The generalized goal is:

- If there is no task that has been finished in some thread so that another task began to run during the certain period of time `threshold`, then a new thread should be created so that other tasks which may potentially run in very short time do not have to wait.
- If there are more than 3 threads that finish at least one task per period `threshold`, one of them should be joined.
- There may be tasks that itself run ad infinitum. This should have no effect on the other tasks.

What could be an appropriate implementation satisfying these requirements or at least doing something related or at least a concept of an implementation?
Or is it completely fine to just create a bunch of threads? (I think about running such an application on a low performance machine like Raspberry Pi and a set of 50 to 300 tasks that should be treated.)

Comment: It looks like you're planning on accessing `abort` from multiple threads. In that case, make it an `std::atomic<bool>`.

Comment: TL; DR; It seems you already must have threads in play, otherwise how can you accept new tasks while another one is still running?

Comment: are you looking for a thread pool?

Comment: You basically want to create a fixed number of threads and schedule tasks among them. Unfortunately, this is not easy to accomplish in C++ in general, since it does not support suspend-resume mechanisms for functions now. Intel TBB or OpenMP provide this functionality. But if you have static tasks (tasks defined before a parallel region), you can also use some simple thread-pool solution.

Comment: imho you are overcomplicating a bit. Why wait for some threshold on each task? You can simply use a number of worker threads and keep them busy. When a task is finished start the next one

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand your problem, but at the same time if seems like you don't understand threading. The thing is that, conceptually, you spawn threads and then provide them with some way of asking for a job. This does not propagate the information about how long it took to finish particular task, but it's also not important since all worker threads will just ask for next task as they finish the current one and will do that independently. Can you show us what exactly you are trying to achieve?